# Real analysis question from olympiad practice book

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math

Below is a question I struggle to solve from an old olympiad textbook

> Let $ a_0, a_1 \dots a_n $ be real numbers and $ 0 < x < 1 $ is fixed which satisfy
>
> $$ \frac{a_0}{1-x} + \frac{a_1}{1-x^2} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{1-x^{n+1}} = 0 $$
>
> We are asked to prove that there exist a real number $ y $ such that
>
> $$ a_0+a_1y+\dots+a_ny^n = 0 $$

I have attempted to observe the question to come up with a solution. I thought since $ 0 < x  < 1 $ we could use infinite geometric series which converge here, I thought about differentiation but cannot proceed with this idea, and I thought about multiplying the given equation by $ 1-x $ and reducing the fractions but I am stuck. I appreciate all help.

Comment: Where are $y_0,y_1...$?

Comment: @Aqua: corrected it's only one $ y $

Comment: There is $x^{n+1}$?

Comment: @Aqua yes corrected that as well, thanks

Comment: $x$ is fixed or variable?

Comment: @Aqua $ x $ is fixed

Comment: I would multiply by $$1-x$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner yes I have tried and get $$ a_0 + \frac{a_1}{1+x} + \dots + \frac{a_n}{1+\dots + x^n} = 0 $$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner could you please give a hint on how to proceed from here?

Comment: And now define $$y=\frac{1}{1+x}$$ and so on.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I cannot see, the powers of $y$ do not correspond to $$ \frac{1}{1+\dots+x^n} $$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expanding in geometric series and defining $a(z)=a_0z+...+a_nz^{n+1}$, you find that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty a(x^k)=0
$$
If the polynomial values in the terms are all zero, your task is done. If one $a(x^k)$ is non-zero, then there has to be some other $a(x^m)$ of opposite sign. Find the root by intermediate value theorem between $x^k$ and $x^m$, that is, also in $(0,1)$.